# YTPlayer will redirect to OAuth2 URL and shows 'please stand by'

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to use [YTPlayer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) for played live stream in iOS App.

I use the simple code and only changed 'videoId' to 'w-T2LJ_qLiw' which is live video at YouTube.

But when video loaded, app will open Safari and redirect to URL as following:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com#rpctoken=840721360&forcesecure=1

and

https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fabc-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Dgapi.gapi.en.dPxK-DAj_pE.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTN0fuoBkyFaoHWfzWWLct0BxZgQSQ#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&rpctoken=2021820196

Then video will loaded and played but covered will black block shows 'Please stand by.'

If video is not 'live', video plays well.

I tried it before yesterday and it works well. What happened to YTPlayer?
I needs to control video's action like, play, pause, reload by code.
Is there any thing I can work around this?

Comment: Great question!  I've tried playing around with it and I there is some kind of forced OAuth call with that video.  I filed an issue on the project's GitHub page [here](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/109).  You can also see how I tried to force the video to play there.  I will let you know if anyone from Google follows up about the issue.

Comment: Thank you JAL!  I've try this morning. No more redirect but error shows like you post at GitHub. Interesting thing is that if I use paid live videoId which is paid channel, it works fine right now. (Yes, even paid channel redirect yesterday.) Seems like YouTube Team were fixed API at that time.

Comment: Looks like the video is working now, can you verify?

Comment: It's not working right now, still needs some solution. Maybe you could re-issue it on GitHub.

Comment: This also appears when trying to stream certain live events using Chrome on OSX. Any solution here? We're using the YT javascript api to embed live videos. Same videos used to work 3-4 weeks ago.

Comment: My fix was merged, this should be fixed if you fetch the latest classes from the repo: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/pull/111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although 周義棠's solution may work, it breaks YouTube's Terms of Service.  I have modified the `handleHttpNavigationToUrl:` method to check for these two additional URLs before taking the user out of the UIWebView and into Safari.

This is my working solution:

```
// YTPlayerView.m

// ...

NSString static *const kYTPlayerOAuthRegexPattern = @"^http(s)://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/(.*)$";
NSString static *const kYTPlayerStaticProxyRegexPattern = @"^https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html(.*)$";

// ...

- (BOOL)handleHttpNavigationToUrl:(NSURL *) url {
  // Usually this means the user has clicked on the YouTube logo or an error message in the
  // player. Most URLs should open in the browser. The only http(s) URL that should open in this
  // UIWebView is the URL for the embed, which is of the format:
  //     http(s)://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEO ID]?[PARAMETERS]
  NSError *error = NULL;
  NSRegularExpression *ytRegex =
      [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:kYTPlayerEmbedUrlRegexPattern
                                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                  error:&error];
  NSTextCheckingResult *ytMatch =
      [ytRegex firstMatchInString:url.absoluteString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [url.absoluteString length])];

  NSRegularExpression *adRegex =
      [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:kYTPlayerAdUrlRegexPattern
                                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                  error:&error];
  NSTextCheckingResult *adMatch =
      [adRegex firstMatchInString:url.absoluteString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [url.absoluteString length])];

  NSRegularExpression *oauthRegex =
      [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:kYTPlayerOAuthRegexPattern
                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                error:&error];
  NSTextCheckingResult *oauthMatch =
    [oauthRegex firstMatchInString:url.absoluteString
                           options:0
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [url.absoluteString length])];

  NSRegularExpression *staticProxyRegex =
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:kYTPlayerStaticProxyRegexPattern
                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                error:&error];
  NSTextCheckingResult *staticProxyMatch =
    [[staticProxyRegex firstMatchInString:url.absoluteString
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [url.absoluteString length])];

  if (ytMatch || adMatch || oauthMatch || staticProxyMatch) {
    return YES;
  } else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
  }
}
```

I have also proposed this change on the project's GitHub as PR [#111](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/pull/111).

EDIT 6/10/15: As of today, this modification has been merged into the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution.

Just stop App jump out by modify method

```
- (BOOL)handleHttpNavigationToUrl:(NSURL *) url
```

from YTPlayerView.m.

Change to following :

```
if (ytMatch || adMatch) {  
     return YES;  
  } else {  
//    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];  
//    return NO;  
      return YES;  
  }
```

or wipe out this method and write just

```
return YES
```

This way has no 'Please stand by...' showing.

Comment: Thanks solution from a friend 'Nick Yu'.
JAL - This will common on GitHub.

Comment: This is really not a good solution, as it blocks taking the user to YouTube if they tap on the YouTube icon on the video.  This breaks YouTube's Terms of Service.  I will post a better answer shortly.